# How to change ConvForm value to string

Tags: php, jquery

I need to take value given by user and change it into php $weight

I tried:
1. giving an input attribute: inputIdName="weight"
2. Many ways to take this value

```
    <input type="text" name="weight" data-conv-question="Your weight?">
<input type="text" data-conv-question="Your weight is {weight}:0." data-no-answer="true">
```

Full Code

```
section id="demo">
        <div class="vertical-align">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-xs-offset-0">
                        <div class="card no-border">
                            <div id="chat" class="conv-form-wrapper">
                                <form action="answer.php" method="GET" class="hidden">
                                    <select data-conv-question="Witaj, pomóc Ci w wyborze idealnego produktu?" data-callback="storeState" name="pytanie">
                                        <option value="tak">Tak</option>
                                        <option value="nie" data-callback="restore">Może później..</option>
                                    </select>
                                                                    <div data-conv-fork="pytanie">
                                                                      <div data-conv-case="tak">
                                                                        <input type="text" name="produkt" data-conv-question="Wporządku, jaki produkt Cię interesuje?">
                                                                      </div>
                                                                      <div data-conv-case="nie">
                                                                            <select data-conv-question="Okej! Jakby co wiesz gdzie mnie szukać ;)" id="" name="pytanie2">
                                                <option value="back" data-callback="rollback">Dzięki!</option>
                                                                                    <option value="no" data-callback="restore">Jednak potrzebuję pomocy</option>
                                            </select>
                                                                      </div>
                                                                        <div data-conv-fork="pytanie2">
                                                                            <div data-conv-case="no">
                                                                                <input type="text" name="produkt" data-conv-question="Wporządku, jaki produkt Cię interesuje?">
                                                                            </div>
                                                                        </div>
                                                                    </div>

                                    <input type="text" data-conv-question="Okej, interesuje Cię {produkt}:0! " value="kategoria" name="kategoria" inputIdName="kategoria" data-no-answer="true">
                                    <input type="text" data-conv-question="Odpowiedz teraz na kilka pytań, które pomogą nam wybrać idealny sprzęt dla Ciebie" data-no-answer="true">
                                    <input type="text" name="wzrost" data-conv-question="Jakiego jesteś wzrostu?">
                                                                    <input type="text" data-conv-question="Więc mierzysz {wzrost}:0." data-no-answer="true">
                                                                    <input type="text" name="waga" data-conv-question="Ile ważysz?">
                                                                    <input type="text" data-conv-question="Ważysz {waga}:0." data-no-answer="true">
```

Comment: Do you have `<form>`? Do you submit this form? If yes - how?

Comment: submit your full code

Comment: Ive edited and added full code, code is not in english, but the question is still the same, how to change those data-conv-question="Ważysz {waga}:0." into $waga

Comment: Its based on this one https://github.com/eduardotkoller/convForm